# Redirect using window.location works only when there is a delay added

Tags: javascript

I am working on a web application developed using Angular and the backend is c#.

**Problem:**
We are using SSO for this application and when the application loads an Axaj call is made to backend and a URL is received from the backend. On the client side in the Ajax call success eventhandler **"window.location= "received URL goes here"** is added. Redirect works in most of the scenarios but only for a few users, it doesn't redirect. But if a breakpoint is added and if we wait for a couple of seconds and then pass the control from the breakpoint the redirect works. Is there something I am doing wrong here while redirecting?

**Tried:**
I have looked at all the suggestions related to this title, none is related to this.

Code snippet for reference:
Redirection

[image: 1]

Comment: try using window.location.href = "recieved url" instead of window.location = "recieved url"

Comment: Please post code, not images of code. Is the $.ajax call made when a form is sent? Do you properly cancel the form submission event?